# How to add an "Add button"?

Tags: java, android

I want to add "Add button" to my application. Which looks like this: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n85J6.jpg). I dont have any idea how to do this, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bottom button in you layout is floating action button and you can create that like below:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

The **layout_gravity** attribute is used to define the position of the button.